# How to convert Raw image texture baked from Blender to sRGB color space

Tags: texturing

I know that to convert from linear to sRGB (or the other way around) you have to apply a gamma correction of 2.2, but how do you convert from RAW to sRGB? I have a whole project using RAW color management because it's much easier to get the right colors when you are doing product texturing, and all of a sudden I'm asked to bake everything for real time. So here I am with all my RAW diffuse textures baked down, and Photoshop opened wondering how to convert them to sRGB space for some final touches in Substance Painter later on.

Comment: Raw in Blender should be linear as far as I know.

Comment: But there is a linear space too, why having it twice?

Comment: That's a good question to ask the developers :D. I think it should be exactly the same as Non-Color Data which is the same as linear, but linear is still supposed to be treated as color data, so there should be some situations where some color transforms might get applied to it so Non-Color is needed, but RAW seems to have no reason to be there at all. Maybe I am missing something and somebody will correct me, but I think it is just a mistake.

Comment: Let's see what the developers say: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/why-are-there-options-for-non-color-and-raw-color-spaces-for-image-textures-arent-they-the-same/9991

Comment: I think this should answer your question why both exist: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#render *Standard* applies the conversion for the display device, while *Raw* is untransformed.

Comment: That's what I assumed, however Non-Color is exactly the same: "For most color textures the default of Color should be used, but in case of e.g. a bump or alpha map, the pixel values should be interpreted as Non-Color Data, to avoid doing any unwanted color space conversions." - from https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html So why are they both [in the Image Texture node](https://devtalk.blender.org/uploads/default/original/2X/d/d2f4edf6d2e82ebdfdc0e97f060c7ec328c2c7aa.png)?.. That must be a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the difference between Linear, Non-Color and RAW Image Texture node's Color Space options seems to be subtle:

- Linear option is for linear **color** space. This means it is color information and will be treated accordingly if color space conversions are needed.
- RAW is still color information, however it is color information that will not be managed in any way and will be as is. It will not go through any color transforms so in Blender's context it will be linear, because that's what Blender uses internally for rendering and calculations.
- Non-Color is information that is not color and will also not be managed as color by color management at all. It will not go through any color transforms and will also remain linear.

You can see that Non-Color and RAW is exactly the same thing in all practical aspects except meaning, while Linear and Non-Color differs in the way Blender should treat the data.

So if you know how to work with Linear color space, the same should work for you with RAW. If you apply gamma of 2.2 to it you will get an approximation of sRGB color space. sRGB is not exactly the same as gamma 2.2 though, but this does not seem important in this context. See https://www.nayuki.io/page/srgb-transform-library for example if you want to know more about it for some reason.